# Запускаю .exe через pyinstaller но мне выдает ошибку, что делать?

Tags: python-3.x

я написал простой скрипт на python и решил его скомпилировать через pyinstaller и у меня произошла ошибка:

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
LookUpError: unknown encoding: utf-8

Current thread: 0×00000958 (most recent call first):
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Какие библиотеки используются в вашем коде?

Comment: в моем коде есть библиотека colorama

Comment: просто с некоторыми библеотеками pyinstaller выдает ошибки